# Parse out 3 strings of data & order by date string in a single file -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an export from a program that currently creates single text files within a folder (10K+ files).

I've built a Powershell command that will parse the data I require from the individual files & combines into a single file however I'm struggling to wrap my head around how I would order these by date value.

The date value in each file is "Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2022 18:14:53 GMT" and is always on line 9 of the file.

Sample output after my powershell script (this is 2 out of 10k+ file exports):

```
Filename: C:\temp\application\006ff9c0-f614-11ec-8f02-11e98e66244e.txt  
From: Test.user@domain.com  
Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2022 12:23:50 GMT  
This is sample message data from the export


Filename: C:\temp\application\00d086e0-cd70-11ec-98d5-6bd60cef152f.txt.txt
From: test.user@domain.com
Date: Fri, 06 May 2022 19:09:07 GMT
This is another sample of message data
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Powershell:

```
clear-host
$MessagesFolder = 'C:\temp'
$MessageSearchLength = 10000
$fileText = @()

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $MessagesFolder -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

Foreach( $File in $Files ) {
  $fileText += "Filename: " + $File
  $fileText += (Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "From:").Line
  $fileText += (Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "Date:").Line
  $message = Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "MIME-Version:" -Context 0, $MessageSearchLength


  Foreach($postLine in $message.Context.DisplayPostContext) {
    if ($postLine) {
      $fileText += $postLine
    }
  }
  $fileText += ""
} 

Out-File -FilePath 'C:\temp\test.txt' -InputObject $fileText
```

Comment: Can you provide what the current output of one of those text files looks like? Are you looking to combine every single line 9 from each file into one file and organize it based on that date format you provided?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala

Sample output from the "C:\temp\test.txt", this out put is just 1 of the previous files that were parsed into (test.txt exports all the previous files into a single file).

Edited the above post with a sample output since I can't seem to understand line breaks in overflow comments.